# How do you interrupt a MyBlock?

Tags: programming, ev3-g

I have a "general-purpose" line-follower encapsulated in a MyBlock that runs an infinite loop.

Now, in a client program, I would like to interrupt that MyBlock if some condition is met; what the condition is should be determined by the client, so I don't want to put that logic into the MyBlock.

I also don't want to terminate the program altogether, and I want to keep the loop in the MyBlock.

Is there a way to break out of the MyBlock?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Loop Interrupt block. Just make sure the name used in the Loop Interrupt block matches the name of the loop inside of the My Block.

[image: Loop Interrupt block]

Comment: Make sure to make explicit calls to turn off the motors